# Show that the relation R on set A is transitive if and only if $R^{n} \subseteq R$ for all positive integers n

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

I tried to prove this using induction but i get stuck at a point and the proof fails. I dont know what am I doing wrong! Can someone help me prove this? I have tried all I possibly could

Comment: Which implication are you having trouble with?

Comment: I started with proving that $R^{2}$ is a relation that exists due to transitivity by definition of composition but i get confused after this. Don't know how to proceed or even if I am doing it right

Comment: @Dissy What do you mean by "relation that exists due to transitivity"

Answer (score 2):

Since this is an *if and only if* theorem, there are actually two implications to prove:

- if $R^n\subseteq R$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, then $R$ is transitive; and
- if $R$ is transitive, then $R^n\subseteq R$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.

The first of these does not require induction. The easiest way to prove it is to prove the contrapositive: if $R$ is **not** transitive, then there is a positive integer $n$ such that $R^n\nsubseteq R$. Suppose that $R$ is not transitive; then there are $a,b,c\in A$ such that $\langle a,b\rangle$ and $\langle b,c\rangle\in R$, but $\langle a,c\rangle\notin R$. By definition, however, $\langle a,c\rangle$ **is** in $R^2$, so $\langle a,c\rangle\in R^2\setminus R$, and therefore $R^2\nsubseteq R$. This shows that if $R^2\subseteq R$, then $R$ is transitive, so of course if $R^n\subseteq R$ for **all** $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, then $R$ is transitive.

For the other direction we have to prove that if $R$ is transitive, then $R^n\subseteq R$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. We can do this by induction on $n$. Of course $R^1=R\subseteq R$; that gets the induction started. Now for the induction step suppose that $R^n\subseteq R$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z^+$; we need to show that $R^{n+1}\subseteq R$. Let $\langle x,y\rangle\in R^{n+1}$; then by definition there is an $a\in A$ such that $\langle x,a\rangle\in R^n$ and $\langle a,y\rangle\in R$. Can you see now how to use the induction hypothesis and the fact that $R$ is transitive to show that $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$ and hence that $R^{n+1}\subseteq R$?

Answer (score 0):

Well the definition of $R^k$ is the set of all $(a,b)$ there that there exist $c_1,...,c_{k+1}$ with $a=c_1, b=c_{k+1}$ and $(c_i, c_{i+1}) \in R$ for all $i: 1\le i < k+1$..

If $R$ transitive and $a,b,c_i$ are as above, if we have $(a,c_1) \in R$ and if we have $(a,c_i)\in R; i\le k$ the we have $(c_i, c_{i+1})\in R$ and as $R$ is transitive we have $(a,c_{i+1})\in R$. So be induction we have $(a,b) \in R$ so $R^n \subset R$.

If $R^n \subset R$ for *all* $n$ then $R^2 \subset R$.  And if $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,c) \in R$ then $(a,c) \in R^2\subset R$ so $(a,c) \in R$.  So $R$ is transitive.